# Bundle PostgreSQL DB with Java application

Tags: java, postgresql, install4j

I want to release a spring boot web application together with a Postgres database. For the installation at the customer, i want to use Install4J.

Are there any best practices to install the two systems at once? Should i separate the two installers and let the customer install one system after the other?

I want to keep it a simple as possible, as the customer is not a person with a strong technical background.

What about licence issues? Do i have to provide the Postgres licence also in my application?

Comment: There is no license issue. You can do with PostgreSQL whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the Postgres installer to the distribution tree and execute the installer in unattended mode with a "Run executable or batch file" action.

The arguments to the Postgress installer should include

```
--mode unattended --unattendedmodeui none
```

These a 4 separate arguments for the "Run executable or batch file" action.